# Prove that any discrete topological space is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

My proof is as follows;

The discrete topology on a set X is given by the family T of all
subsets of X. So every singleton set {x}, x ∈ X, is open in this
topology.

So, for any two distinct points x, y ∈ X, we have that {x} and {y} are disjoint and open.

So we have found open neighbourhoods of two arbitrary and distinct points in X, so X is Hausdorff.

Is this proof sufficient? I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the point x, and the singleton set {x}; so I'm not sure if {x} counts as a neighbourhood around x.

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. A neighborhood is an open set or a set containing an open set around a point, depending on the author. In the discrete topology, $\{x\}$ meets both criteria.